Handling different auth flows for AzureAD - internal vs external accounts AzureAD B2C
I'm working on looking at a way to architect two auth flows, given one azureAD tenant.
Internal users: AzureAD users that have client (or client-associated) email domains. Their SSO onboarding is fully managed already via EntraID.
External users: AzureAD users that have any other email domain. There wont just be a handful, instead several thousand.
The idea is that there will be a page in an application that will ask if the user is an employee or client - internal or external.
The requirements from an application perspective are as follows:

Internal users go down the predefined route already set up in the existing tenant
External users have a customised auth flow with hosted auth pages
For both sets of users, there should be the premise of a hierarchy of user types (permission based)
External admins should be able to add/delete their own users via application (this is an important part of the self-service nature of application)

Coming from an AWS Cognito background, I'm fairly new to AzureAD and would appreciate some steer given this starter for ten:

Questions:

Can AzureAD B2C be leveraged and its IDP be that of the main tenant?
Should these external users be utilised by means of another tenant altogether?
Can auth flow for internal and external users be combined?


Yes - use federation (also works for user flows)
The login screen will then have two options:

Federation to Entra ID
Local to B2C

